# php function that make numbers and chek if exist in array and make a new

Tags: php

I'm struggling to make a PHP function that will generate numbers. This is the basic functionality I need.

If the number already exists in the array, it needs to be able to randomly select a new number.

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

```
<?php
$lines= array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
function lineOne($line){
     if($line == null ){ $line = 1; }
     if( in_array($line, $lines) ){
          $line = rand(6, 10);
          lineOne($line);
          break;
      }
     echo $line;
}
lineOne();
?>
```

Comment: This is a variable scope issue. Look closely ..hint `$lines`

Comment: Nah i cannot see it :-/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
<?php
$lines= array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
function lineOne($line){
     global $lines;
     if($line == null ){ $line = 1; }
     if( in_array($line, $lines) ){
          $line = rand(6, 10);
          lineOne($line);
          break;
      }
     echo $line;
}
lineOne();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe pass the variable as a parameter instead of using the global keyword.;)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out a noob ;-D

Comment: @Akintunde I would in my code, but I'm just looking for quick points to get to 2k